Ao carregar um registro cadastrado selectonemenu não fica com o valor correto
Criei uma aplicação para praticar JSF 2.2, nela cadastro marca, modelo e por fim o avião. Na tela de cadastro do avião tenho dois selectonemenu, um para selecionar a marca e outro para selecionar o modelo (os modelos exibidos dependem da marca selecionada). O cadastro dos aviões corre bem, mas ao tentar carregar um avião na tela os campos selectonemenu não estão trazendo a marca e modelo do avião.
Imagem demostrando o problema
aviaoBean
package bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import dao.DAO;
import modelo.Aviao;
import modelo.Marca;
import modelo.Modelo;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AviaoBean {
    private Aviao aviao = new Aviao();
    private Integer marcaId;
    private Integer modeloId;
    private List<Aviao> aviaoSelect = new ArrayList<Aviao>();

    public Integer getModeloId() {
        return modeloId;
    }
    public void setModeloId(Integer modeloId) {
        this.modeloId = modeloId;
    }
    public Aviao getAviao() {
        return aviao;
    }
    public void setAviao(Aviao aviao) {
        this.aviao = aviao;
    }
    public void gravarAviao() {     
        new DAO<Aviao>(Aviao.class).adiciona(this.aviao);
        this.aviao = new Aviao();
    }
    public List<Aviao> getAvioes() {
        return new DAO<Aviao>(Aviao.class).buscaTodos();
    }
    public Integer getMarcaId() {
        return marcaId;
    }
    public void setMarcaId(Integer marcaId) {
        this.marcaId = marcaId;
    }
    public List<Modelo> getModelosPorMarca() {
        return new DAO<Modelo>(Modelo.class).buscaPorMarcaId(marcaId);
    }
    public void gravarDadosAviao() {
        Marca marca = new DAO<Marca>(Marca.class).buscaPorId(marcaId);
        this.aviao.setMarca(marca);
        
        Modelo modelo = new DAO<Modelo>(Modelo.class).buscaPorId(modeloId);
        this.aviao.setModelo(modelo);
    }
    public List<Aviao> getAviaoSelect() {
        return aviaoSelect;
    }
    public void setAviaoSelect(List<Aviao> aviaoSelect) {
        this.aviaoSelect = aviaoSelect;
    }
    public boolean nenhumAviaoSelecionado() {
        return aviaoSelect.isEmpty();
    }
    public boolean maisDeUmAviaoSelecionado() {
        return aviaoSelect.size() > 1 || aviaoSelect.isEmpty();
    }
    public void removeAviao() {
        for(Aviao aviao : aviaoSelect) {
            new DAO<Aviao>(Aviao.class).remove(aviao);
        }
    }
    public void carregaPeloId() {
        Integer id = aviao.getId();
        this.aviao = new DAO<Aviao>(Aviao.class).buscaPorId(id);
        
        if (this.aviao == null) {
            this.aviao = new Aviao();
        }
    }
    public void carregaAviao() {
        this.aviao = aviaoSelect.get(0);
    }
}


aviao.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@latest/primeflex.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="aviaoId" value="#{aviaoBean.aviao.id}"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{aviaoBean.carregaPeloId}" if="#{param.aviaoId != null}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form id="aviaoForm">
        <p:fieldset legend="Cadastro Avião">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="field grid col-6">
                    <h:outputLabel for="marca" value="Marca: "
                        style="margin-right: .5rem" />
                    <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="marca" value="#{aviaoBean.marcaId}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma marca" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{marcaBean.marcas}" var="marca"
                                itemLabel="#{marca.nome}" itemValue="#{marca.id}"/>
                            <p:ajax update="modelo" event="blur"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:linkButton outcome="marca" icon="pi pi-plus"
                            title="Cadastro Marca" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field grid col-6">
                    <h:outputLabel for="modelo" value="Modelo: "
                        style="margin-right: .5rem" />
                    <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="modelo" value="#{aviaoBean.modeloId}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um modelo" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{aviaoBean.modelosPorMarca}" var="modelo"
                                itemLabel="#{modelo.nome}" itemValue="#{modelo.id}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:linkButton outcome="modelo" icon="pi pi-plus"
                            title="Cadastro Modelo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{aviaoBean.gravarAviao}"
                update=":avioesCadastradosForm"
                actionListener="#{aviaoBean.gravarDadosAviao}" />
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>


    <h:form id="avioesCadastradosForm">
        <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Editar"
                    disabled="#{aviaoBean.maisDeUmAviaoSelecionado()}"
                    style="margin-right: .5rem" id="editaButton" action="#{aviaoBean.carregaAviao()}" update=":aviaoForm:marca :aviaoForm:modelo" />
                <p:commandButton value="Remover"
                    disabled="#{aviaoBean.nenhumAviaoSelecionado()}" id="removeButton" action="#{aviaoBean.removeAviao()}" update=":avioesCadastradosForm" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>
        <p:fieldset>
            <p:dataTable value="#{aviaoBean.avioes}" var="aviao" rows="10"
                paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                selection="#{aviaoBean.aviaoSelect}" selectionMode="multiple"
                rowKey="#{aviao.id}" rowSelectMode="add">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":avioesCadastradosForm:removeButton :avioesCadastradosForm:editaButton" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":avioesCadastradosForm:removeButton :avioesCadastradosForm:editaButton" />

                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{aviao.id}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Marca">
                    <h:outputText value="#{aviao.marca.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Modelo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{aviao.modelo.nome}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>


RESOLVIDO!
 public void carregaAviao() {
        this.aviao = aviaoSelect.get(0);
        this.marcaId = aviao.getMarca().getId(); //faltava setar id da marca e modelo ao carregar o avião
        this.modeloId = aviao.getModelo().getId();
    }

